# Twitter Widget Only Showing Link on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, widget

I am simply trying to embed an active Twitter feed on to my website.
I have followed all of the steps on the Twitter website for the widget (under the settings) and for what ever reason instead of showing the 350 by 350 widget on the HTML page all it displays is the link to the twitter page.

Here is my simple code (given by twitter) and some screenshots.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="350" data-height="350"     href="https://twitter.com/Coltae">Tweets by Coltae</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the code??

Comment: Added it sorry!

Comment: Look in the console, maybe a request is blocked _for some reason_...

Comment: I have. No luck  . . .

Answer (score 0):

The link in the `src` property is missing the `https://`part. Just add that and you're probably fine.